# dropdown toggle not responding to key commands

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've isolated a malfunctioning component from my project.

I'm trying to enable tab selection for an input search element with a drop down selector

I'm using hosted jquery / bootstrap libraries

Problem: When i tab from the input element to the dropdown component, and hit the down key, the drop down shows, but i can't use the up or down arrows to navigate through the dropdown elements.

Expected: I should be able to use the arrow keys to navigate items in the list. The example in the documentation is keyboard selectable, and shows a corresponding focus state.

Documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups

Example HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Action <span class="caret"></span></button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /btn-group -->
        </div><!-- /input-group -->
    </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
</div><!-- /.row -->
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YXNMB/

Comment: the bootstrap documentation is very sparse. You are not the first one who has been confused by the "documentation" and the actual use. The best thing you can do, is to look at the code by yourself and by that be 100% sure.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add role="menu" to your dropdown UL like so:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" role="menu">
```

Without the role="menu" the dropdown component doesn't associate the arrow keys with the drop down elements.

Comment: Strange that it's not in the example code on the bootstrap website.

Comment: It's definitely in the example code: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns

Comment: On the page he referenced http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups on the buttons with drop-downs section, the example code omits role="menu" from the ul element. Inspect element shows the actual ul element has role="menu" though.

Comment: Good catch, they need to update that documentation.  I've created an issue on the bootstrap project: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/13697